# Multiple users on one account: session data

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, multiple-users

I figure that this should be possible, as it is a requirement asked by my supervisor. There are a few types of accounts, one of them is a 'company' account which should allow anyone in the company who has these credentials to log in at the same time.

Now my question is, how do I store temporary data like: 
(this is fictive)
shopping carts, keeping track of wizards,...
I suppose that I'll have to store this in the database?
What would be my best option. Link it to the unique session id?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store sessions in your database if you like. A nice way to do it, is by creating a sessions like table that stores states. Therefore, if you have a cart, you can have a cart table that represents what products the cart has and replay that after a user logs back in.

Answer (score -1):

Session information isn't  based on your account-system but on the system of the visitor (cookie). Unless you want all information to be shared across all users logged in on the company account (which I doubt) you shouldn't have to store any of the information in the database.

To store the data you can simply keep using session (as I suppose you already do for the 'normal' account.

Comment: Actually, the first statement is wrong. If sessions were based on the client, that would be very very bad for security :) Sessions are generated from the server. Also, a session is not persistent as a db is, so it expires. That is why a db is sometimes needed.

Comment: each session is unique and cannot be shared across "all users"